# Can't save data with postgreSQL in prod profile

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

When i launch my server with prod profile, I can connect with admin admin in my JHipster application, but I can't save any data when I want to create a new object (I have an InternalServerError). However in dev profile with the same database (PostgreSQL) it's working well.

Moreover I don't know how to get logs when using prod profile to understand the problem.

I can add the configuration file for the prod profile

```
# ===================================================================
# Spring Boot configuration for the "prod" profile.
#
# This configuration overrides the application.yml file.
# ===================================================================

# ===================================================================
# Standard Spring Boot properties.
# Full reference is available at:
# http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
# ===================================================================


spring:
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: false
        livereload:
            enabled: false
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/vraiJhipster
        name:
        username: vraiJhipster
        password:
    jpa:
        database-platform: com.mycompany.myapp.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL82Dialect
        database: POSTGRESQL
        show_sql: false
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: false
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
    data:
        elasticsearch:
            cluster-name:
            cluster-nodes: localhost:9300
    mail:
        host: localhost
        port: 25
        username:
        password:
    thymeleaf:
        cache: true

liquibase:
    contexts: prod

server:
    port: 8080
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css, application/javascript, application/json
        min-response-size: 1024

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
    http:
        cache: # Used by the CachingHttpHeadersFilter
            timeToLiveInDays: 1461
    cache: # Hibernate 2nd level cache, used by CacheConfiguration
        timeToLiveSeconds: 3600
        ehcache:
            maxBytesLocalHeap: 256M
    security:
        rememberMe:
            # security key (this key should be unique for your application, and kept secret)
            key: *****************************************
    mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
        from: vraiJhipster@localhost
    metrics: # DropWizard Metrics configuration, used by MetricsConfiguration
        jmx.enabled: true
        spark:
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 9999
        graphite:
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 2003
            prefix: vraiJhipster
        logs: # Reports Dropwizard metrics in the logs
            enabled: false
            reportFrequency: 60 # in seconds
    logging:
        logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 5000
            queueSize: 512
    swagger: # swagger is disabled. It can be disabled by pasing 'no-swagger' profile at run time as well
        enabled: false
```

Thank you.

If you need something about my configuration you can ask it.

Comment: Please share more specific information such as Stacktraces, Code Snippets, or even a full sample application on GitHub.

Comment: How do you run your app in prod profile: mvn, executable jar, deployed war in an external server? Which JHipster version?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I use Jhipster 3.4.2 (latest version) and i launch the server with spring so I guess it works with mvn.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by "i launch the server with spring". Do you mean you start your app from command line as an executable jar or using 'java -jar'? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-running-your-application

Comment: Actually I used mvn -Pprod

Comment: inside of `LoggingAspectConfiguration` you can temporarly comment out the @Profile annotation, which will print more details about which exception is causing your internal error...then maybe we can help you

Comment: Thank you so i know from where it's coming now. It's elasticsearch the problem, when I created my project I said I wanted to use elasticsearch, but I have to use a local cluster, when I'm in production profile. [Jhipster Documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/using-elasticsearch/). I think I do not need elastic search. I guess I have to generate a new project. Maybe I can modify something on my existing project to delete elastic search automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it was actually elasticSearch. When I use JHipster in production mode, the default configuration use elasticSearch on port 9300. But I hadn't any elasticSearch running on my computer. So I copy pasted the elasticSearch configuration from dev profile to prod profile.

```
data:
    elasticsearch:
        cluster-name:
        cluster-nodes:
        properties:
            path:
              logs: target/elasticsearch/log
              data: target/elasticsearch/data
```